Add Networked Printer
How to add a Epson ET-3700 printer on home network?
I tried the ADD PRINTER box, by entering the printer's IP address. No result.
The other computer on the network is Win10, and has no problem printing.
Epson does not seem to offer driver for linux.

You've not provided any Ubuntu product or release details; please tell us what you're using; as these details let us know what options exist for you.

The ET-3700 should not require any drivers, as it is supposedly IPP-compatible. Make sure your Ubuntu system is really on the same subnet as the printer.

Ubuntu 24.04
I will look into the arrangement of two switches in my home network to see if it makes a difference.
